# Component/Integration Tests failing for @Async annotation in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I'm facing an error while running Component/Integration Tests in SpringBoot project containing @Async annotation in one of the classes.

When I remove that @Async annotation it works fine.

My code briefly looks like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class MyAsyncConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
  }

}
```

The @Async annotated method looks like below:

```
@Service
public class AsyncOperations {

  @Async
  public void doAsyncOperations() {
    // Some business logic here
  }
```

The code works totally fine when I hit my API from Postman. The Async operations happened asynchronously as expected, but when I run the Component/Integration Tests using mvn verify command, I get an error like below:

```
Caused by: Java.lang.IllegalStateException:Failed to introspect class [className] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoader]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method "$jacocoData" in class (AsyncOperations) has illegal signature
```

Comment: It's possible you're facing an issue similar to [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549438)

Comment: Yes, the issue seems similar, but there isn't any solution provided in that link. So does that mean the issue is still outstanding? :\